# Proteger rutas en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, vite

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de React con Vite y Firebase, necesito proteger las rutas admin, formulario y tabla, para que no puedan acceder hasta no validar que esta autenticado, ya tengo un variable que válida la autenticación, pero no sé cómo implementarlo en las rutas, espero alguien me pueda ayudar                               [image: Así está mi archivo de rutas]

Comment: El codigo como texto y formateado como codigo con las herramientas del sitio, no como imagenes

Comment: La variable que válida la autenticación (supongo que en un estado) donde la obtienes? De el componente <App>? De un contexto?

Comment: Ya que son pocas rutas, probaste modificar los respectivos componentes de modo que no cargue su contenido? Lo mejor sería acceder a dicha variable con `useContext`. Entonces escribirías `return useContext().variable ? mostrar : <div></div>` o algo así. O de qué manera quisieras hacerlo?